# How to read and write input CSV file at the same time reliably with Ruby?

Tags: ruby, csv

I am using Ruby to parse a CSV file. Lines look something like this:

```
NOT_PROCESSED:COLUMN1:COLUMN2:COLUMN3....
NOT_PROCESSED:COLUMN1:COLUMN2:COLUMN3....
NOT_PROCESSED:COLUMN1:COLUMN2:COLUMN3....
```

I am parsing the whole line and after processing I want to change first column NOT_PROCESSED to PASSED or FAILED accordingly. So after file is processed it should look like this:

```
PASSED       :COLUMN1:COLUMN2:COLUMN3....
FAILED       :COLUMN1:COLUMN2:COLUMN3....
PASSED       :COLUMN1:COLUMN2:COLUMN3....
```

How to do that with Ruby correctly?
Years ago I used code that looked like this:

```
CSV.open("File.csv", 'r+', { :col_sep => ':' } ) do |line|
   old_pos = line.pos
   account = line.shift
   # PROCESSING CODE....
   line.seek(old_pos)
   account[0] = '%-13s' % status   # status can be "PASSED" or "FAILED"
   line << account
   line.flush()
   old_pos = line.pos
end
```

Now I am running this code on a newer machine that has new OS version as well as new ruby and gem versions. It seems that code above is not running reliable anymore, in some cases it even corrupts input CSV file.

Most of the lines are still ok after processing but there are also multiple lines that are malformed - something like this (for example part of line is missing):

```
LUMN1:COLUMN2:COLUMN3....
```

There can also be some empty line inserted or 2 lines merged into one etc.
What would be the best way to achieve what I want?

Comment: have you thought of using a database, rather than a CSV for managing your data?

Comment: Well, this could maybe be an option, but am looking into solving it on CSV level first if possible.

Comment: Can you explain what "not running reliable anymore" and "corrupts input CSV file" means? There is almost no possible way this is "corrupting" the file since CSV files are simply delimited txt files. I am assuming by "corrupting" you mean that the data is malformed, or otherwise incorrectly altered, after processing, if so an example would be highly beneficial.

Comment: do you have an option to read all of the csv into memory process it however you need it and then write it after you are done?

Comment: I don't understand your question. Can you give an example that shows images of the input file and the desired output file, the files having just a few lines (perhaps 4-5) and perhaps two or three fields?

Comment: I wouldn't have made my request if I understood what the CSV files looked like. For example, `NOT_PROCESSED:COLUMN1:COLUMN2:COLUMN3...` looks like a header in a CSV file but your `CSV.open` statement indicates that the input file does not contain a header.

Comment: I edited opening post to answer some of your questions. Please note also that COLUMN1, COLUMN2 and so on represent data in that columns, not header. COLUMN data can be numbers, strings, or it can also be empty.

Comment: Seems like `# PROCESSING CODE....` may be the cause (we have no idea what this does). Have you looked at the original lines that cause the issue? Is there something different about these lines? Also trying to determine why `account[0]` rather than `account.unshift` since you already "shifted" "NOT_PROCESSED" I would assume you would unshift "PASSED"/"FAILED"

Comment: please add the PROCESSING CODE.... to your question as a real example of your input and output

Comment: The value of `status` is not defined in `CSV::open`'s block, but whatever it is (presumably `"PASSED"` or `"FAILED"`) it does not change within the block so how can some lines in the output file begin `"PASSED"` and others begine with `"FAILED"`? What does "accordingly" mean in your second sentence? When you say "Lines look something like this:", it would be clearer if an example line were something like (I'm guessing) `"LUMN1:6:3:18:..."` instead of `"LUMN1NOT_PROCESSED:COLUMN1:COLUMN2:COLUMN3...."`.